# How to see what changed in Windows Store apps?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store, software-update

Is there any way to see "change logs" of my Windows Store applications when they come up as available for updates? I can't seem to get any information about what actually changed in several of my apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the application in the Updates list to select it, then click View Details.

[image]

If there are multiple updates available, you'll need to click Clear first, as this button only appears when there is exactly one update selected.
[image: Clear]

You will then see Release Notes:

[image]

Comment: Nice spot! I'd missed that, I'll remove my answer :)

Comment: Another item hidden in not-so-much plain sight, but it makes sense... Thanks!